# Database query : [Union] / [or condition in where clause]

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sybase

I have to fetch record based on TransDate and ValueDate

Fetch record based on following criteria :

1. TransDate is on or before 20th march 2016 and ValueDate is on 20th march 2016
2. ValueDate is on or before 20th march 2016 and TransDate is on 20th march 2016

My colleague try to use UNION with following query

```
  select * from Sales where ValueDate < '2016-03-21' and ValueDate >= '2016-03-20' 
    and TransDate < '2016-03-21'
Union 
  select * from Sales where TransDate < '2016-03-21' and TransDate >= '2016-03-20' 
    and ValueDate < '2016-03-21'
```

But I felt rewrite that query to following way

```
select * from Sales where ((ValueDate < '2016-03-21' and ValueDate >= '2016-03-20' 
    and TransDate < '2016-03-21') or (TransDate < '2016-03-21' 
    and TransDate >= '2016-03-20' and ValueDate < '2016-03-21'))
```

Note : Both TransDate and ValueDate are timestamp datatype.

Kindly suggest the difference of both query, else if any other approach is best suggest me.

Comment: both query will produce same results but difference may be in performance and can't say which will perform better...it will depend query execution plan and how much data in your tables and how much data is filtering by your conditions...so check your own and use which is better....your query is performance wise better than suggested by @Dylan as suggested query will not use index efficiently due to date function.

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Table contain millions of record, it will filter around 5k to 10k  records.

Comment: transdate and valuedate fields are indexed?....and much time your both queries are taking...

Comment: Yes both are indexed TransDate is holding timestamp but valuedate is holding only date without timestamp.

Comment: `UNION` though cleaner will slow down the performance because it will actively check and remove duplicates from your result set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in results between the two queries. But the time cost time maybe different.

I think the 2nd will be faster.

Here is another option:

```
select * from Sales 
where 
    (DATE(ValueDate) = '2016-03-20' and TransDate < '2016-03-21') or 
    (DATE(TransDate) = '2016-03-20' and ValueDate < '2016-03-21')
```